# Keras: How to make average/maximum operation on top of some layers results?

Tags: python, keras

I design neural network with the dynamic amount of inputs. My idea is to process set of data with shared model, then average/maximum their results and place classifier on top of it.
After reading documentation i was sure that it is possible using Keras, but i faced problem that `keras.layers.average` can receive only input tensors. But i need to make this operation over models or other layers instead.

Here is code i have now

```
inputs = [Input((countInputCount,))]  # count is always here
downs = []
for i in range(count):
        inputs.append(Input((inputCount,)))
        downs.append(sharedDown(inputs[-1]))
avg = keras.layers.average(downs)
max = keras.layers.maximum(downs)
middle = keras.layers.concatenate([inputs[0], avg, max])
```

For this i got next error: `ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs.`

Probably i understand this error incorrectly. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need input layers. The merge layer expects a *list* of inputs (i.e. a list of tensors), not a list of `Input()`s.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was in fact for the edge situation with the 1 tensor in a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact `keras.layers.average` works for any tensor, but not accept list of one tensor. So if you will face something similar you can handle with the single if statement:

```
if count==1:
  avg = downs[0]
else:
  avg = keras.layers.average(downs)
```